# Ask assistance for finding K. Sato - Lévy Processes on the Euclidean Spaces

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, paper-request, levy-processes

The paper me and my professor want is called *K. Sato (1995) Lévy Processes on the Euclidean Spaces, Lecture Notes, Institute of Mathematics, University of Zurich*.

I tried to find the paper on the official website of Zurich University but I failed (so sad almost there).

The author Sato Keniti created his own [page](https://ksato.jp/) and put the access of his very paper, listing this note there though, but no access was put.

My professor said it is a very good paper for us to learn Lévy's process (if you want to learn it you could refer to it, it is a nice introduction). I will be very grateful for any help!

Comment: since prof. Sato links to pdf's of his other lecture notes, but not of these from 1995, it seems most likely that no pdf is available.

Comment: For what it is worth, prof. Sato has a very nice introductory book on Levy processes.

Comment: You might try to contact K. Sato directly, by email.  The most recent (2018) of the papers listed on his website contains an email address (and it's the same address as the 2014 paper, so seems to be stable).

Comment: Thank y'all! Ur the best ;) I'm gonna contact him with email and read other materials of him. It's just my professor he can't find it either, so I begging for your guys. |ω・） Thank you all again~